# How to convert a Python deque to a C++ container?

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api, deque, python-extensions

I have to pass a Python deque to a C++ function but I can't find any documentation on how to convert a deque to a C++ container (for this case, either a deque or a vector would do). Searched everywhere but I couldn't find a solution. There's gotta be a simple way to do this right?
Thanks

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque

Comment: that site says nothing about how to copy a Python deque to a C++ deque?

Comment: One basic issue is that a c++ container holds a specific type, while a Python container can hold any type. You have to decide what you want to do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "simple way". You'll need to do that by hand (or maybe with some kind of interface generator), in a data-specific way.

Take a look at [C API Introduction — Python 3.8.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html) for an overview of Python data model at C level. It has absolutely nothing to do with any C++ types.

You'll need to somehow extract the data you need from Python objects, via Python C API, and construct the C++ structure you need from that.

SWIG may help you here. Take a look at [SWIG-4.0 Documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn18) -- it has [a section](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn18) about how to do conversion between C++ types and those from a scripting language.

Comment: thanks! is this compatible with other tools like boost and the standard API?

Comment: AFAICS, SWIG acts in a library-independent manner. So it doesn't matter what specific types you are dealing with -- standard, boost or whatever else.